# No dreaded diamond in python?

Tags: python

My first language(programming) C++,And now I started off with python and I could see unlike java which don't do multiple inheritance to avoid dreaded diamond problem(hopefully), the python seems to have multiple inheritance and as far as I have seen, it doesn't throw ambiguity error when I do multiple inheritance, I knew,C++ has virtual inheritance to avoid diamond prob, and now I am sort off looking how python handles it even it doesn't use any keyword for that(doen't py actually have this problem?)or I am not getting the right scenario to fallen into the diamond prob?

```
class super:
   x=0
class sub1(super):
   pass
class sub2(super):
   pass
class sub3:(sub1,sub2)
   def prin(self):
       print(self.x)
```

when I do `ob=sub3();ob.prin()` things went fine(Hmmmm,why its because of the 
L->R `(sub1,sub2)` associativity or any subtle implementation detail behind it?)

Comment: Required reading: [Python's super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). Not sure any answer could explain it better.

Comment: At least you shouldn't shadow the builtin [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) with a class, as it is used to delegate method calls to parents or siblings...

Comment: See [documentation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).